# How would I go about adding admin functionality for non-technical people for a telegram bot I coded in node.js?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I have created a telegram bot with node.js, and was wondering whether it was possible to allow admins to directly alter the code of my bot without directly accessing the code?

For example if they typed a command "somecommand/edit"

It would allow them to directly edit the response of a certain command, in the telegram app input box itself. The current way commands get edited are, someone tells me to change something, and I push it to github after making changes directly to the files. Is there a simpler way for the non-technical admin to directly make changes to the files without needing me?

I understand this may seem a little confusing, So I am glad to help clarify.

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a few approaches here.

1. You can add a config file (JSON or similar) and edit the contents when an admin runs a command
2. Save the message to a database and create a simple user interface to change the value

Then have the message be a variable referencing the config file or database rather than hard coding it.